# How to use addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I've got an issue with `addEventListener`.

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("nb1").value);
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("nb2").value);
document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", calculate(x, y));
function calculate(x, y) {
    document.getElementById("result").value = x + y;
}
```

When I execute this code, the function calculate is directly called without me clicking the button "calculate". I really don't understand why, could you help please ?

Comment: `addEventListener("click", calculate(x, y)` will execute the function. No need to pass the arguments as `x` and `y` are global variables. Try this: `document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", calculate);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In provided snippet, value of total will never be the expected value as you are storing values of `input` field initially not when using is clicking `calculate` button.

To get the updated values, you need to get the values when `click` event takes place.

Also note, `addEventListener` expects second argument to be function expression. In your case you are invoking function `calculate` which will be executed when particular line of code is executed. If you want to pass arguments in function expression then -> `function(){ calculate(x, y); }`

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", calculate);

function calculate() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("nb1").value);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("nb2").value);
  document.getElementById("result").value = x + y;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id='nb1'>
<input type="text" id='nb2'>
<br>
<input type="text" readonly id='result' placeholder='Result'>
<br>
<button id='calculate'>Calculate</button>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/x9jjwznL/)

Answer (score 1):

Use callback like `function(){  calculate(x, y); }`, your code will immediately execute the `calculate(x,y)` and won't wait for the event to fire.

```
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("nb1").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("nb2").value);
    document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function(){  calculate(x, y); });

function calculate(x, y) {

     document.getElementById("result").value = x + y;

}
```

Comment: means on click it will execute calculate function,right ?

Answer (score 0):

When you say `functionName(param1, param2)`, it will call that function and return its value. So when you assign it to event listener, you are assigning its return value. If you want to pass arguments while assigning, you should use `bind`.

**Note:** *This will only work once,  since you are assigning value to `x` and `y` only once. @Rayon Dabre's answer is ideal way.*

```js
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("nb1").value);
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("nb2").value);
document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", calculate.bind(event, x, y));


function calculate(x, y) {
  document.getElementById("result").value = x + y;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="10" id="nb1" />
<input type="text" value="20" id="nb2" />
<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
<input type="text" id="result" />
```